# Prevent HTML (previously printed content) from appearing in JSON response

Tags: php

I am developing a WordPress plugin that needs to download and install a plugin.

In the response there is some unknown HTML output, possibly injected from the specific plugin that I am installing, making the response look like so:

```
<div class="wrap"><h1></h1></div>{"success":true}
```

How do I ensure no HTML/content is outputted, without having control over the actual plugin/code that executes it?

I have tried fiddling around with `ob_clean`, like so:

```
// my plugin installer script
ob_start();

// execute code to install plugin
// this plugin might generate/echo some content
// that I need to make sure is not included in the final response,
// as the client expects raw JSON to be returned.

ob_end_clean();

header('Content-Type: application/json');

exit(json_encode([
    'success' => true
]));
```

But it doesn't seem to work. HTML is still returned.

I suspect I might be using the `ob_clean` function the wrong way, but I'm not certain, since I haven't used it much prior to this.

Comment: I suppose that "code to install plugin" is doing something like `ob_flush` at some point. The better approach would be to make these lines not output anything. Can you share what plugin that is and how you use it? (I personally don't know much about WP, but maybe someone can help you out.)

Comment: @Jeto they shouldn't output anything, but I don't have control over infinite amount of wordpress plugins, so that we I need to handle it somehow. The code basically runs some installer scripts, as seen here: https://gist.github.com/simplenotezy/c6ce5ffcdd0e420f4e4a606b2506c3a3

Comment: `activate_plugin` has a [`$silent` option](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/activate_plugin/#parameters), for instance, which might help. I'd look into stuff like that at least.

Comment: @Jeto thanks for pointing me in that direction. I would like to hooks to be fired still. Anyway, I tried it, and it didn't seem to do the trick.

Comment: @Jeto I figured it out! Gist updated: https://gist.github.com/simplenotezy/c6ce5ffcdd0e420f4e4a606b2506c3a3/edit

Comment: Nice! (last link doesn't work, but I found it from the one above)

Comment: Great @Jeto - correct link is: gist.github.com/simplenotezy/c6ce5ffcdd0e420f4e4a606b2506c3a3